# onChange event is not triggering in Mozilla and IE React js/Redux

Tags: javascript, file, reactjs, redux

I am pretty new guy to react js.I am little bit confused why input type=file action is not working in Mozilla and IE it is  working fine in Chrome.I don't why it is not working...Haaa that is pretty hard to find my mistake.I know this might be a simple noobie Mistake
Pls help me

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import uuid from 'node-uuid'
    import * as headerAction from '../../Actions/headerActions';
    import * as uploadActions from '../../Actions/uploadActions';
    import * as notificationActions from '../../Actions/notificationActions';
    import shortid from 'shortid'

    class Header extends React.Component{
        static contextTypes = {
            router:React.PropTypes.object
        };

        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.Hovered = this.Hovered.bind(this);
            this.UnHovered = this.UnHovered.bind(this);


        }
        UnHovered(){
            this.props.toggleMenu(false);
        }
        uniqueNameAndId(){
            return uuid.v1().replace(/-/g, '');
        }
        //below function not triggered When onChange Event happen But file upload popsup
        handleFileUpload(e){
           //Not working
             e.preventDefault();
             this.props.setMainPostId(shortid.generate())

//Upload for single File not working
            const reader = new FileReader();
             //const file = e.target.files;
            //console.log(file.length);
            reader.onload = () => {
                console.log("Hello",file.name)
            };

            let file = e.target.files[0];
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    //Upload for Multiple files NOt working
            {/*if(file.length <= 5){*/}
                {/*for(let i=0;i<file.length;i++){*/}
            //         const Reader = new FileReader();
            //         Reader.onload = () => {
            //             let pushData = {
            //                 postOwnerUsername:null,
            //                 id:this.uniqueNameAndId(),
            //                 name:this.uniqueNameAndId(),
            //                 caption:null,
            //                 blobData:Reader.result
            //             };
            //             console.log(pushData)
            //             this.props.pushtoReducer(pushData)
            //         };
            //         Reader.readAsDataURL(file[i])
            //     }
            //     this.props.removeUploadMenu(false)
            //     this.context.router.push('/upload');
            // }else{
            //     console.log('No Dude')
            //     this.props.popErrorNotification(true,"#FF5D5D","Current Max Photo 5")
            // }




        }
        loggedInMenu(){
            return(
                <div>

                    <li>Explore</li>
                    <li>My uploads</li>
                    {this.props.toggle.removeUploadMenu ?
                        <li>
                            <label htmlFor="upload-photo">Upload</label>

                            <input onChange={this.handleFileUpload.bind(this)} id="upload-photo" type="file" multiple/>
                        </li>:
                        ""
                    }

                    <li>Profile</li>
                    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                </div>
            )
        }
        loggedOutMenu(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <li onClick={()=>this.props.toogleSignInOut(true)}>SignUp/SignIn</li>
                    <li>Explore</li>

                </div>
            )
        }
        renderMenu(){
            return(
                <div onMouseLeave={this.UnHovered}>
                    <div  className="dtcen">
                        <div className="dt">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="dropdown">

                        {this.props.logInStatus.loginStatus ? this.loggedInMenu():this.loggedOutMenu()}


                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        Hovered(){

            this.props.toggleMenu(true);
        }
        render(){

           // console.log('From uuis',this.uniqueNameAndId())
            //console.log("Login Status",this.props.toggle.removeUploadMenu)

            return(

                <header>
                    <div className="logo">
                        <p>Masklor </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navtoggle">
                        <div onMouseEnter={this.Hovered} className="triangle">
                            <p>Menu</p>
                        </div>

                        {this.props.toggle.menuToggle ? this.renderMenu() : ""}

                    </div>
                </header>


            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return{
         toggle:state.toggle,
          logInStatus:state.logInStatus,
          photos:state.photoUpload
      }
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return{
            toggleMenu:bool => dispatch(headerAction.toggleStatus(bool)),
            toogleSignInOut:bool => dispatch(headerAction.toggleSignPop(bool)),
            pushtoReducer:object => dispatch(uploadActions.setPhotosState(object)),
            popErrorNotification:(bool,color,message) => dispatch(notificationActions.popUpNotification(bool,color,message)),
            removeUploadMenu:bool => dispatch(headerAction.removeUploadMenu(bool)),
            setMainPostId:id =>dispatch(uploadActions.setIdforMainPost(id))
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Header)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code might be generating javascript functions inside control flow blocks, in chorme ie will work fine but wont with mozilla, so you will have to put functions outside conditional blocks, see my sample:
In mozilla, this wont work:

```
function myDataCall(data) {
    if(data) {
        processData(data);
        function processData(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work:

```
function myDataCall(data) {
    //Work, cross browser compatible
    if(data) {
        processData(data);
    }
    function processData(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, regards!